# Merge sort Recursion Error

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

```
   Mergesort(a,p,r){
     if(p<r){
       int q=[p+r]/2;
       Mergesort(a,p,q);
       Mergesort(a,q+1,r);
       Merge(a,p,q,r);
```

It's from the book Introduction to ALgorithms:Cormen
in this i can't understand the recursive call of the merge sort algorithm

```
                   2 4 1 6 8 5 3 7 
               2 4 1 6         
              2 4 
             2
```

in the first recursive call i got upto three then where does the control goes from here i m struck at 2 will it call the next function mergesort(a,q+1,r) and merge(a,p,q,r) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417540/douglas-crockfords-javascript-the-good-parts-chapter-5-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your array is `a = { 2, 4, 6, 1, 8, 5, 3, 7 }`. I swapped two elements of the array proposed by you. Now, what follows is exactly what your program does, call after call.

---

At the first call `p=0, q=7`: your while array is the input.
At the second call `p=0, q=3`, at the third `p=0, q=1`.

At the fourth call `p=0, q=0`: the input is the subarray `{ 2 }`. This array has just one element, thus is sorted: the line `if(p<r)` makes sure the fourth call ends here and control returns to the third call.

The third call has the input `{ 2, 4 }`. We have just ended the line `Mergesort(a,p,q);`, thus we know the first half of the input is sorted. The *fifth* call (line `Mergesort(a,q+1,r);`) will now sort the second half.

At the  fifth call `p=1, q=1`. The input is once again an array of length 1, thus sorted by default. Control returns to the third call.

The third call is now evaluating the line `Merge(a,p,q,r);`. The first half is sorted, the second half is sorted: `Merge(a,p,q,r);` takes those two halves and shifts the element making sure the **whole** subarray from index `p` to index `r` is sorted. The third call ends.

The second call had `{ 2, 4, 6, 1 }` has input. The first half is sorted, now remains the second half: after that call the input become `{ 2, 4, 1, 6 }`. After `Merge` is called the input become `{ 1, 2, 4, 6 }` and the second call ends, returning control to the first call.

The first call now needs to sort the second half of *its* input, that incidentally is the whole array. That is done as before.

Comment: i got upto the recursive call Merge(a,0,0) ,Merge(a,1,1,),Merge(a,2,2,) and Merge(a,3,3) now how can the fifth expression is evaluated ?   @Asghabard