# Extract & call JavaScript function defined in the onclick HTML attribute of an element(using jQuery attr/prop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having 2 buttons A & B and I need to call the function defined in onclick HTML attribute of button B but on click of button A.

Also I need to pass an extra param to that function in this case.
buttons are like:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_a">  
<input type="button" id="btn_b" onclick="return doSomething(p,q)">
```

I want to make a call like:

```
doSomething(p,q,r) // 3rd param to identify that it was clicked via button A
```

**Button B is actually a variable button & gets the p,q params dynamically & I need to pass the 3rd param along.**

button B can have onClick attribute like

`onClick= return doSomething(122,334) or return doSomething(abc,54)`

or any other values.
I need to call the function such that

```
doSomething(122,334,'btn_a') or

doSomething(abc,54,'btn_a')
```

how to achieve this using jQuery/JS? I was able to call the function using the `.prop()` but couldn't figure out passing the additional param.

I was able to call the function like:

```
<script>
    jQuery('#btn_a').on('click',function(){
      (jQuery('#btn_b').prop('onclick'))(); //this can invoke the function but how to pass the additional param?
    })
  </script>
```

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36078980/4763793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, i.e. use `attr` instead of `prop` to get the string value of b's **onclick**, afterwards replace the arguments `p,q` from the string with `p,q,r` and then use **Function constructor** to create an anonymous function with the new body (after replace).

```
jQuery('#btn_a').on('click', function(){
    var onclickB = jQuery('#btn_b').attr('onclick'),
        onclickA = Function(onclickB.replace("p,q", "p,q,r"));
    return onclickA();
});
```

***Note***: you can do anything with this approach, just create a regex pattern to replace anything with what you want.

Comment: I was thinking the same way but I wondered if prop can help me invoke the function there might be a way as well to pass an additional param using a JS feature?

Comment: actually what prop returns is a function like `function onclick () { return doSomething(122,334); }`, so even if you can pass custom arguments to the outer function `onclick`, there is no such way (besides parsing as string) to pass those params to internal function calls.

Comment: if by using attr we extract "doSomething(122,334)" can I pass the param with any other way instead of replace?

Comment: I was thinking if that was possible by using call apply or some of inner JS feature that I dont know

Comment: moreover to do onclickB.replace("p,q", "p,q,r") I will need to extract p & q from the attr retrieved string.

Comment: Not exactly the solution but I used this idea..thanks Ammar.. :)

Comment: If the additional param is a variable containing an object or array we will have to stringify it as it cant be attached directly.. what do you say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the function doSomething like below, pass null for btn_b and pass value for btn_a. Hope this helps.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btn_a">  
<input type="button" id="btn_b">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#btn_a").on("click", function() {
        return doSomething(p,q,r);
    });


$("#btn_b").on("click", function() {
        return doSomething(p,q,null);
    });


function doSomething(p,q,r){
        if(r != null){
        //do something for btn_a and return
        } else {
        //do something for btn_b and return
        }

    }
```

Comment: that wont do because p & q are assigned dynamically

Comment: button B is in a loop & gets p & q from there,so it is like onClick= return doSomething(1123,3335) or any other numbers strings.I need to get it from the onClick attrib & then call it with additional param

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="button" id="btn_a" onclick="return doSomething(p,q,r)">`

Comment: that wont do because p & q are assigned dynamically – techie_28 3 mins ago

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple you can set some global variables/object you want to pass into function as parameters and then call the function and use global variables/object property value.

What you say ;)

```
/* with variables in global scope should be accessible inside function going to call */
param1 = 1;
param2 = 2;

/* function definition */
function functionCalling(){
  /* use values here */
  console.log(param1, param2);
}

...
functionCalling();
...

/* with variables in global scope should be accessible inside function going to call */
param = {property1:1, property2:2};

/* function definition */
function functionCalling(){
  /* use values here of object */
  console.log(param.property1, param.property1);
}

...
functionCalling();
...
```