# Function Typecasting JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Recently I had asked a question

[Extract & call JavaScript function defined in the onclick HTML attribute of an element(using jQuery attr/prop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078655/extract-call-javascript-function-defined-in-the-onclick-html-attribute-of-an-e)

I needed to programmatically access the onclick attrib of a button which had a function call along with param's in it then supply an extra param & make a function call(`onclick=doSomething(2,4)`).

But as I figure out that the use of `apply/call` can also come handy to supply extra param's.For this I extracted the the function name from the attribute & it comes in a string like

```
arr[1] = 'doSomething';
```

I tried using **Function Constructor** to treat this as a function but it doesn't work
(like `Function(arr[1])`) Why?

Solution mentioned [Javascript: interpret string as object reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953303/javascript-interpret-string-as-object-reference) works fine. But why it cant be achieved via the function constructor?

Some code info

```
 var funDef      ='doSomething'; // this is the name of real function defined in the script
 var funcName    = new Function(funDef); //expected it to return reference of function doSomething,shows function anonymous() in console

    var funcArgs    = [5,7,10];
    funcName.apply('',funcArgs); //this is the function call.
```

In this case function **does not get called** untill I replace

```
    var funcName = new Function(funDef); with var funcName = eval(funDef);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `new Function` constructor works like `eval()`. So `new Function(arr[1]+"()");` might work.

Comment: Do share a fiddle....

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol how to pass additional params then?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Maybe `new Function("return " + arr[1] + '()')`

Comment: @techie_28 you can call another function on the on click event, with these parameters. And from that function you can call the actual function with the desired parameters.

Comment: @Atif my question is different here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed this on the JavaScript chat room from where I understood that `new Function(..)` constructor needs whole function body to return reference in the way I was expecting.

The function constructor does not consider the definition of the `doSomething` function that is written in the script while `eval` does.

Other ways that could be fit in this scenarios are here:

[Javascript use variable as object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name)

Comments?

Answer (score 2):

`new Function` and `eval` are not interchangeable. When you eval, you are creating code that runs immediately. When you create a `Function`, that is going to return a function that you can run yourself.

It's almost as if you do:

```js
// This executes 1+2
var resultOfEval = eval('1+2');
// This creates a function that when called, returns 1+2
var resultOfWrappedEval = eval( '(function(){return 1+ 2})' );
// This is much like the line above, you have to call it for it to execute
var resultOfFunctionCtor = new Function('return 1+ 2;');


console.log('resultOfEval', resultOfEval);
console.log('resultOfWrappedEval', resultOfWrappedEval);
console.log('executing resultOfWrappedEval', resultOfWrappedEval());
console.log('resultOfFunctionCtor', resultOfFunctionCtor);
console.log('executing resultOfWrappedEval', resultOfFunctionCtor());
```

If you show more of your code, we can suggest something, but the key is that when calling the Function constructor, the code doesn't run immediately, it returns a reference to the newly created function.

Also, you seem to understand that you can call the function yourself. What is the problem with doing that?

Comment: Yes I did not expect it to run immediately but I expected the `var funcName` to get the reference of the function `doSomething` whose name I am extracting as a string from `arrArgs[1].slice(0,arrArgs[1].indexOf('(')) this gives doSomething` the call to the function is `funcName.apply('',funcArgs);` which does not gets called in this case unless I do `var funcName    = eval(arrArgs[1].slice(0,arrArgs[1].indexOf('(')));`

Comment: looks like `var funcName = new Function(arrArgs[1].slice(0,arrArgs[1].indexOf('(')));` is not referencing the function despite getting name correctly i.e `doSomething` from `arrArgs[1].slice(0,arrArgs[1].indexOf('('))`

Comment: I have to extract onclick attribute because there is dynamic params there which are different everytime.